# *** Error in `./prog5': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001cc3260 *** Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, memory-management

I am working on a program that reads in a text file and dynamically allocates memory that is the same size as the text file.  It then lets the user choose different options to perform on the data from the text file.  One of these options is to search for a certain character by entering in a decimal number (0-255) or hex number (0x00-0xFF).  Whenever I test this option, I get a double free or corruption error that is associated with freeing the memory allocated for a pointer to the place in memory for the entered character.  The function I have written performs the given task correctly except for stopping the program due to this error.  I have included the function code along with my own function safeFree which free the allocated memory and makes the pointer NULL.  If I do not free the memory, the program will keep executing but with memory leaks.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
char *find=(char *)malloc(5*sizeof(char));
int num;
printf("Enter a decimal 0-255 or hex value 0x00-0xFF.\n");
scanf("%s",find);
while(getchar()!='\n');

if(strncasecmp("0x",find,2)==0)
{
    num=strtol(find,0,16);
}
else num=atoi(find); 
safeFree(find);
printf("num=%d",num);

if(num<0 || num>255)
{
    printf("Invalid entry for this option.\n");
}
else
{
    char *locptr=malloc(sizeof(char));
    locptr=strchr(data,num);
    if(locptr<data || locptr>data+a) printf("Character not found.\n");
    else
    {
    while((long int)locptr%16!=0) locptr-=sizeof(char);
    printf("\n\t\t");
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<16; i++) printf("%d  ",(i%10));
    printf("\n[%lu]\t",(long int)locptr);
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        printf("%c  ",*(locptr+i));
    }
    printf("\n\t\t");
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        printf("%2.2X ",*(locptr+i));
    }
    printf("\n\t\t");
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        if(*(locptr+i)==num) printf("^  ");
        else if(locptr+i<data || locptr+i>data+a) printf(".  ");
        else if(*(locptr+i)=='\n') printf("   ");
        else if(*(locptr+i)=='\0') printf(".  ");
        else printf("   ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    safeFree(locptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the implmentation of `safeFree`?

Comment: You don't check if `malloc()` was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
char *locptr=malloc(sizeof(char));
locptr=strchr(data,num);
```

is recipe for disaster. You should not change the value of pointers that you use as handles to allocated memory, because that handle wil be used when you free the memory.

Here, you have changed the address and actually try to free another part in memory, possibly even memory on the stack (depending on where `data` resides).

Also, you shouldn't allocate memory for just one temporary `char`. That's like asking to rent a suqare foot of a flat. You are probably mistaken on how to use pointers. You don't have to allocate memory for every pointer. Most pointers point to something that is already there, like the result from `strchr`: It either is `NULL`, which means it doesn't point anywhere, or it points to a valid char inside the searched string. There is no need to allocate here.

Therefore, this:

```
char *locptr=malloc(sizeof(char));
locptr=strchr(data,num);
if(locptr<data || locptr>data+a) printf("Character not found.\n");
```

should be:

```
char *locptr = strchr(data, num);

if (locptr == NULL) printf("Character not found.\n");
```

The result can only be outside of the sraeched string's range when it is `NULL`. (That's guaranteed by the implementation of `strchr`.)

Comment: Ahhhhh! Thank you very much!  What you said makes a lot of sense and I see the problems behind what I did.  I have done the same kind of thing numerous times in other parts of my programs.  Changing this fixed those as well.  Thank you for enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect code here:

```
char *locptr=malloc(sizeof(char));
locptr=strchr(data,num);
```

Because the strchr returns pointer to the first occurrence of character in string. You do not need malloc/free for locptr.

Details: [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/)

BR,
Alex